# SQL Server output using Pivot

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Table detail

```
Column_name     Type
-------------------------
Id              int
ProductId       int
Product         nvarchar
ProductDetails  nvarchar
```

Table data

```
Id  ProductId   Product ProductDetails
---------------------------------------
1   1           Name    IPhone
2   1           Price   40000
3   2           Name    Nokia
4   2           Price   20000
```

I want result using pivot like this:

```
Product Price
-------------
IPhone  40000
Nokia   20000
```

Comment: please Add the Query you tried. and add create table and sample data script.

Comment: i am totally stuck

Comment: we are also too ;-) suraj answer's is good try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following inner join.

```
Create table TblProducts (Id int,
ProductId       int,
Product         nvarchar(20),
ProductDetails  nvarchar(20))

insert into TblProducts Values
(1,   1,           'Name', 'IPhone'),
(2,   1,           'Price', '40000'),
(3,   2,           'Name', 'Nokia'),
(4,   2,           'Price', '20000')

Select a.*, b.ProductDetails from(
Select * From TblProducts where Product = 'Name'
)a inner join(
Select * From TblProducts where Product = 'Price'
)b on a.ProductId = b.ProductId
```

Here is the live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b796fd1fbebbd63957325976289941ba) demo.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply do *conditional* aggregation :

```
select max(case when product = 'Name' then ProductDetails end) as Product,
       max(case when product = 'Price' then ProductDetails end) as Price
from table t
group by ProductId;
```